Mensaje de alerta en javascript cuando realiza una accion de envio
tengo un codigo de un carrito de compras, actualmente cuando la persona oprime la opcion de comprar me envia un mensaje muy vago de su compra es exitosa, necesito que cuando la persona de la opcion de comprar me aparezca una alerta en javascript de gracias por tu compra su pedido esta siendo procesado pero no se como insertar eso en esta parte del codigo que tengo.
La parte en especifico que deseo modificar para que me haga la alerta es:
// Construir la consulta SQL escapando los valores


$query = "INSERT INTO pedidos (fecha, nombre, correo, telefono, total, productos,tipoentrega,direccionentrega) VALUES ('$fecha', '$nombre', '$correo', '$telefono', '$total', '$productos', '$tipoentrega', '$direccionentrega')";

// Ejecutar la consulta SQL
if (mysqli_query($conexion, $query)) {
    $respuesta = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Correo enviado correctamente');
} else {
    $respuesta = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error al registrar el pedido en la base de datos');


Por favor, presiona [edit] y agrega la parte del código que recibe/lee la variable $respuesta

En realidad ya tienes todo lo necesario, solo falta que le metas el script que quieras en el momento donde sabes que que la compra fue realizada con exito
$compra = true;
if ($compra == true) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Compra Exitosa !!!");</script>';
}

En tu caso sería algo como
$query = "INSERT INTO pedidos...)";

// Ejecutar la consulta SQL
if (mysqli_query($conexion, $query)) {
    $respuesta = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Correo enviado correctamente');
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Compra Exitosa !!!");</script>';
} else {
    $respuesta = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error al registrar el pedido en la base de datos');

Ahí es donde puedes meter un Sweet Alert o, también puedes redireccionar a una pagina especifica que de muchísima más información que solo una compra exitosa.
Yo prefiero esto ultimo, hago una pagina landing donde informar al cliente sobre el éxito de la compra y otras cosas más como que es lo que ha comprado, alguna promoción, detales de facturación y un montón de etc más 

Excerlente solucione el problema con tu mensaje. muchas gracias...

Por favor, marca la respuesta como Aceptada si te ayudó a solventar tu problema
